# Exporting true color sentinel image in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google, sentinel-2

I tried to download a sentinel image, but it seems not to work. It downloads a one band image and not 4,3,2 rgb combination as coded.

This is the code I'm using that just downloads 1 band:

```js
var marco = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-70.33198356628418, -16.667604212318242],
      [-70.33138275146484, -16.64129056542051],
      [-70.3795337677002, -16.641043857880046],
      [-70.3795337677002, -16.668426455517558]]]);


var sentinel = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180726T144731_20180726T145459_T19KCB').select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']);

Export.image.toDrive({
 image: sentinel,
 description: 'imageToDriveExample',
 scale: 10,
 region: marco
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The code works:

[image]

The result is a multiband raster with:

- Band1: band4 of S-2
- Band2: band3 of S-2
- Band3: band2 of S-2

Comment: When I download it from Drive, the image weighs 100 kb and is all dark.

Comment: @AlvaroMorales this image has a size of 880 kb. Maybe something is wrong with your Google Drive